# Does a Chalav Yisroel milk bottle help?

Tags: kashrut-kosher, chalav-yisrael-jewishmilk

There are many stores out there (e.g. Coffee shops) that have a hechsher, but are Chalav Stam. To get around this issue, some of these stores offer the option to request Chalav Yisroel milk for those who need it.

For visualization purposes: the store carries a Chalav Yisroel milk bottle. When a customer requests it, the storekeeper will substitute the standard milk with the milk from the Chalav Yisroel bottle.

My question, though, is whether this actually helps the Chalav Stam/Akum issue? After all, if the milk bottle is sitting in the store throughout the day, do we not suspect that the storekeeper (who's presumably a gentile) may mix the milk? Shouldn't this "Chalav Yisroel" milk once again become Chalav Stam/Akum milk?

---

Clarification: My question is due to my understanding that milk in particular requires an extra level of supervision. For example, in order to make milk Chalav Yisroel, it is required to have a Jew supervise the actual milking process. This is very much unlike other products where concepts such as נכנס ויוצא (perhaps best translated as "spot checking") do work.

So: the hechsher I referred to in this case is merely serving the purpose of providing a basic level of Kosher supervision - and confirming that the milk in question does indeed qualify for the "Chalav Stam" leniency. The milk in question, on the other hand **was** at one point Chalav Yisroel (according to the label), but is **now** sitting in the store - open and unsupervised. Does this change its status?

[If it helps: it's also possible to construct this case without any hechsher at all: simply pick your favorite unflavored coffee scenario that's permissible anywhere and add a Chalav Yisroel milk bottle. Was just trying to boil the case down a bit...]

Comment: Why wouldn't it need to have some sort of hashgacha just like any place that serves treif and kosher, particularly when a substitutable product is cheaper and readily available?

Comment: I understood chalav yisroel to be a marker on the authenticity of the milk on the farm level - as not having been tainted by milk from another animal by a farmer who was not jewish. thus being switched in a store is not the concern unless a storekeeper (why "presumably a gentile" btw?) has a horse in the back room.

Comment: @Dan He may not have a horse in the back room, but he may have not chalav yisrael milk == possible horse milk.

Comment: @DoubleAA in that sense, any customer should be worried if he wants (kosher) cow's milk, but the concern isn't one of cholov yisroel status. it is of kashrus. if you walk into shoprite and the fish guy says he has a separate knife for kosher fish how do we know that he does not switch knives? kashrut.com says this is acceptable if the store has "good supervision." same idea. if you can rely on the hashgocha, wouldn't it apply to this as well? there is no notion of cholov shenitaleim min ha'ayin, is there?

Comment: @Dan Exactly my thoughts in my first comment.

Comment: @DoubleAA As I write in the question, suppose the store *does* have an Hashgacha. My question is focusing on the Chalav Yisroel issue. According to my understanding, Milk in particular is singled out as requiring an extra level of watching so that standard principles (e.g. Nichnas Veyotzei) aren't good enough. So the hashgacha in this case is simply saying that the store is Kosher - but the milk it uses relies on Chalav Stam.

Comment: @Dan see my previous comment: Once again, in this case the hashgocha is merely applying a level of supervision, and says that the milk is coming from sources which are deemed Kosher using the Chalav Stam leniency. In no way do they indicate that there is a Chalav Yisroel level of Hechsher.

Comment: If the Chalav Yisroel bottle is not sealed from the source then this certainly does sound like a problem to me! Kashrus fraud, I'm sorry to say, happens a lot more than people expect.

Comment: @yydl, perhaps spell out the "According to my understanding, Milk in particular is singled out as requiring an extra level of watching so that standard principles (e.g. Nichnas Veyotzei) aren't good enough." in the question? +1, though.

Comment: @msh210 You're correct - edited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per [Ohr Yisroel 20:186](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=13598&hilite=7af57952-cbd7-4516-9bfe-c83983231992&st=%D7%97%D7%9C%D7%91+%D7%99%D7%A9%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%9C&pgnum=186) this is indeed a problem and it would be inappropriate to drink such milk if one is Makpid on Chalav Yisroel.

Comment: Looks like Ohr Yisroel is a collection of Halachic essays from various authors. So it may be more correct to say per Rabbi Yisroel Amram Nagel of Boro Park published in Ohr Yisroel..